# Caret C5.0 warnings

Tags: r, r-caret, c5.0

I wonder if something is going on with my syntax or with `caret` here?  I'm using the `caret` package in R Version 4.2.3 to build a boosted tree model using `C5.0`.  I'm consistently getting the same type of warnings: [image: R Screenshot]

I originally thought that this was due to something having to do with my data, but I tried using the sample data and code in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/vignettes/C5.0.html) with `caret` and ran into the same warnings.

```
library(modeldata)
library(caret)
library(C50)
library(tidyverse)

data(credit_data)
vars <- c("Home", "Seniority")
set.seed(2411)
in_train <- sample(1:nrow(credit_data), size = 3000)
train_data <- credit_data[ in_train,] %>%
    filter(!is.na(Seniority)) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Home)) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Status))
 
#Using C50
C5.0(Status ~ Home + Seniority, data = train_data)
#Using Caret
train(Status ~ Home + Seniority, data = train_data, method = "C5.0")
```

The train function in `caret` throws the warnings.  The C5.0 function from `C50` does not.  Is there something wrong with `caret` or my syntax here?

Comment: It throws warnings but what does it return?

Comment: normal output...so maybe it's a problem with my data?  When I run the code with my own data, with specifications for trControl , tuneGrid, and metric = "ROC", I get the same type of warnings.  calling the model object in the command line shows that the ROC values all = 0.5 for every trial; all of the Sens values are 0 and all of the Spec values are 1.  Not sure what's happening.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the question has changed and I'll work on a new post with new sample data.  I'm familiar with the "rule" and followed it on the original post, so there's no cause to be rude, which is also a rule here.

Comment: You know some of the conventions. Why not learn the one about not posting with images of code or output? And including  MCVE?